# Code assistance in Netbeans on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, error-detection

My IDE (NetBeans) thinks this is wrong code, but it compiles correctly:

```
std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
std::cout << add(5, 7) << std::endl;
std::string test = "Boe";
std::cout << test << std::endl;
```

It always says `unable to resolve identifier .... (.... = cout, endl, string);`

So I think it has something to do with the code assistance. I think I have to change/add/remove some folders.  Currently, I have these include folders:

**C compiler**:

```
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include-fixed
/usr/include
```

**C++ compiler**:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/i486-linux-gnu
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/backward
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include
/usr/include
```

What could be causing this, and how can I make NetBeans mark it as valid code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me. I'm using NetBeans 6.8; the only undefined reference I got was for the add() function.

Can you test with a new project to see if you can reproduce the problem?

**EDIT (reply):**

Yep, tested on Linux. No includes added in project properties.

In the global C/C++ options I have an extra include path for C,  `/usr/include/i486-linux-gnu`.
For C++ I have:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4
/usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu
/usr/include/c++/4.4/backward
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include-fixed
/usr/include/i486-linux-gnu
/usr/include
```

These are my defaults, haven't touched them. HTH
I also use gcc-4.4.3 (Ubuntu 10.04).

Comment: Do you also work with linux? If, so, can you see any diff with your include folders?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the proper includes?

If I remember correctly, you need to

```
#include <iostream>
```

Comment: It's not having any problems with the include? Then you don't have a problem with the include paths, that's for sure. Try compiling it from the command line, so that we can localize the problem.

Comment: But it compiles without any problems. The IDE debugger think it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools->Options->C/C++->Build tools, it will show the compiler NetBeans is using.
E.g.

```
    /usr/bin/g++
```

Typing in a terminal:

```
    $ whereis g++
    g++: /usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/X11/g++ /usr/share/man/man1/g++.1.gz
    $ ls -al /usr/bin/g++
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Mar 13  2012 /usr/bin/g++ -> g++-4.6
```

Will show which version of the compiler Netbeans is using.  If the libraries in the Code Assistance tab do not match, you need to change them for the ones of the right version.
E.g.

```
    /usr/include/c++/4.6
    ...
    /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed
```

and so on.